# Is there a way to cancel a POST once it has been submitted without using AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, post

This is a JavaScript question, but not an AJAX question. Is there a way to cancel a post once it has been submitted and is in motion?

- So the user hits the post button - all is well and form is submitted PHP is ready to catch the details.
- For whatever reason there is network congestion and the server does not respond.
- I want to give the user a chance to post again after a time has passed.

Is there a way to cancel the actual POST once it has been sent?

Is there a way to actually detect - on the server side - that a post was received? (In this case data is to be saved in the database)

I'm imagining the whole post procedure has a beginning and an end on the server side?

Or is there a way to know for sure that the post is going nowhere? It has failed and that's the end of it?

Comment: you can simply check database if the record added or not and notify the user about that.

Comment: I would probably use AJAX for this, as Stack Overflow does. If you submit a comment, but your connection is bad, then it will pop up a little box explaining that the server could not be contacted. If you do this using a regular POST, then the whole screen will fail to load, and you'll be relying on your back button to remember the data the user entered.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to cancel the actual POST once it has been sent?

No, not from the server. Only from the client. You can chose to not respond to the request, but to cancel it "in the middle" is not possible from the server *without some overly complicated acrobatics which you really shouldn't be doing*.

> Is there a way to actually detect - on the server side - that a post
>   was received?

Your code will only run once a request is received; so by default - if your code is running - request is received. You can use any of the logging mechanisms provided by PHP to log this event; or just check the web server logs.

> I'm imagining the whole post procedure has a beginning and an end on
>   the server side?

Everything starts from the client, and it ends with the client as well. The client requests a resource. If there a no clients, your code is sitting idle twiddling its thumbs. Once the server receives a request from a client, it maps the request URL to a resource and then needs to deliver a response back to the client.

All web requests happen this exact same way. They are started from the client's side; and they all end when the client receives a response and the connection is closed. Then the whole cycle starts again for a new request.

> Is there a way to know for sure that the post is going no where. It
>   has failed and that's the end of it?

If your code was not called; then there was an error at the server end (perhaps misconfiguration). The key thing to remember is the client will always get a response; and it is up to you to figure out what happened.

The best way to do this is to have smart logging in your application - or generally monitoring the server logs (where are requests are tracked).

If a post has gone "no where", the corresponding log entry will tell you.  If the log entry does not show any errors and the action that you had expected (for example, a database record was created) hasn't happened - this means the problem was with your code.

If you have a requirement to make sure that a record was created *only if a request was successful* then use [transactions](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php) if your database supports them.